# Object with handle 0 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab has a function called `setappdata`. From this [book](http://www.amazon.de/Accelerating-MATLAB-Performance-Speed-Programs/dp/1482211297) (the chapter about caching) I have learned that cached data can be stored using `setappdata` in a mysterious object 0 like this:

```
setappdata(0,'CachedData',[0 1 2 3]) % I am caching vector [0 1 2 3]
```

The question is, what is object 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have discovered the Matlab root object, `0`.

All matlab GUI objects have `handles` - including the root, which is 0.

Prior to R2014b all graphics handles were represented by what appeared to be a number, but infact was a pointer to the graphics handle.

You will find that all GUI that you create has the ability to store appdata.

Setting data in the 0 object -> this will mean that you can get it from anywhere (but it can also be overwritten from anywhere...) -> so its best to store data linked to your application:

```
hFig = figure;
setappdata ( hFig, 'variableName', yourVariable )
```

To get the data you use:

```
cache = getappdata(0,'CashedData')

% or post R2014b you can use:
cache = getappdata(groot,'CashedData')
```

Comment: does it have something to do with `groot`? If yes, then can I access the cashed data by using `r` which comes from `r=groot`?

Comment: Yes `groot` is the post `r2014b` name for it (they are in essence the same thing)

Comment: @matlabgue Do you know in what property / with what method of `groot` I can access my cashed values?

Comment: @SergeyZykov `getappdata(groot,'CachedData')`